# How can get Touch of 2 Fingers at a Time?

Tags: android

I click 2 fingers on a SurfaceView at a Time, i want get X,Y of 2 Points:

This is my code, but it only get X,Y of 1 Finger.

How can get X,Y of 2 Fingers at a Time?

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {           
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int ipoiter = event.getPointerCount();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(ipoiter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(int i=0;i<ipoiter;i++){
                int x=  (int)event.getX(i);
                int y = (int)event.getY(i);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
     }
}
```

I had try below code but `action=0`, so can't process.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(action), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
              int ipoiter = event.getPointerCount();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(ipoiter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for(int i=0;i<ipoiter;i++){
                    int x=  (int)event.getX(i);
                    int y = (int)event.getY(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` is triggered for each newly touched point on screen.
to get the all touch points try something as follows.
You will get the active finger points in `mActivePointers`

```
private SparseArray<PointF> mActivePointers = new SparseArray<PointF>();

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

        // get pointer ID
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

        // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
        int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (maskedAction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            // We have a new pointer. Lets add it to the list of pointers

            PointF f = new PointF();
            f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            mActivePointers.put(pointerId, f);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // a pointer was moved
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                PointF point = mActivePointers.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (point != null) {
                    point.x = event.getX(i);
                    point.y = event.getY(i);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointers.remove(pointerId);
            break;
        }
        }
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
```

Source : [Check this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html#exercise-multitouch)